# Remote connection to MySQL Linux

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I opened up ports on my server

(results of netstat -L)

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 *:mysql                  *:*                     LISTEN
```

...

but i can't connect to my server on that port via telnet, or remotely to my MySQL server.  I am at my wit's end.  How can I allow remote access on this port?

mysql -u -h 'my-server-ip' gives me an error that says '(HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'my-server-ip' (10061)

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: SOLVED see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebooted my server and it worked :S

for any future readers, i opened up port 3306 on my firewall, inbound and outbound.  then i commented out the binding_address line in my my.cnf file.  i also granted access to remote users using phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the correct port open in iptables?  MySQL usually listens on port 3306, but above you have port 3389 (which is usually used for RDP).

Comment: thanks for that, i actually copied the wrong row of the table.  i edited my question, it now says *.mysql like the output does